# Magento / PayPal - Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order

Tags: magento, paypal

customer can not place order

they already agreed to terms and it asks again at "review order" page

i tested and confirmed this bug happen on PayPal express only

stuck and can not checkout

error on page says: Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order

http://oi46.tinypic.com/ekrbsx.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Check in `paypal.xml` if agreement block is commented or not. May be paypal is not knowing whether customer has accepted Terms or not.

Also try logging to see if the agreement value is going yes or not in checkout page.

Answer (score 1):

this solved issue:

1) Rename paypal.xml to paypal._xml within “app/design/frontend/YOURTHEMEdefault/layout/” (mag 1.7)

2) Remove the paypal API credentials from the config and save

3) Put the API credentials back again and save

Comment: you forgot most important thing, Clearing the cache :P

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue and neither of the other answers helped in my case so I signed up to post the solution I found.

Go to:

> app\design\frontend[yourtheme][yourskin]\template\checkout\onepage\agreements.phtml

Move the `</form>` on like 41 to the bottom of the template.

Done.

If it isn't on line 41, basically what you need to do is make it so that the form with id 'checkout-agreements' is INSIDE the form 'discount-coupon-form'. That worked for me.

Comment: that should say move the form end tag on line 41. This thing removed my text?